# Produce login error only if not correct login

Tags: php, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I know this has something to do with the num_rows part but after numerous attempts I still can't figure this out. Basically no matter what I enter I am receiving the 'login failed' message. If my login is correct I receive login failed and login correct. I obviously only want the error if the username/password are incorrect. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
else if(!$error_msg && $_POST['login']){
//Build the SQL query to match the record that matches the password and username
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password_1 FROM members WHERE username = ? AND password_1 = ? LIMIT 1";
//Prepare our query
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
        //Bind the Parameters to the query
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password_1);
    //Execute the query
    $result = $stmt->execute();
        //If the query doesn't execute
    if($result === false){
        echo '<p class="error">No Execution</p>';
    }
        //Bind the results of what the query gave us to our three variables
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $password_1);
    if($stmt->num_rows !== 1){
        echo '<p class="error">Login failed</p>';   
    }
        while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo "Hey The query matched a record and you should be signed in now";
        echo $id;
        echo $username;
        echo $password_1;
    }//End While
    else{
    echo $mysqli->error;
    echo "No entry found";
}
$mysqli->close();           
}
```

Comment: For a successful login, try `if($stmt->num_rows >0){ echo "Success"; }`

Comment: This does not return any message.

Comment: Did you try placing it just below `$result = $stmt->execute();` ?

Comment: yep, just empties the form and nothing shows up. I don't understand how I can have a record and display it but num_rows comes up empty

Comment: Have a look at what I posted below. Pre-tested and working on my server ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, working on my server.

Some of your conditional statements are missing, but am sure you can incorporate them into it.

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$mysqli = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");

$username = "username"; // replace with actual
$password_1 = "password"; // replace with actual

$sql = "SELECT id, username, password_1 FROM members WHERE username = ? AND password_1 = ? LIMIT 1";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){

   $stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password_1);

   /* execute query */
   $stmt->execute();

   /* Store the result (to get properties) */
   $stmt->store_result();

   /* Get the number of rows */
   $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

   /* Bind the result to variables */
   $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $password_1);

if($stmt->num_rows !== 1){
    echo '<p class="error">Login failed</p>';   
}

   while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo 'ID: '.$id.'<br>';
        echo 'Name: '.$username.'<br>';
        echo 'Password: '.$password_1.'<br>';
   }

   /* free results */
   $stmt->free_result();

   /* close statement */
   $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: It Worked thanks man, so I guess basically I wasn't storing the result of the query so there was nothing to pass num_rows. THANKS!!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. @bilcker and exactly. They can be tricky at times, but I figured it out. Sometimes a fresh pair of eyes helps and I'm always happy to help find a solution, cheers.